# Is there an R function to get the max value of a variable appearing several times across several years?

Tags: r

I am trying to get the max value of a variable appearing several times across several years between two lists. For example, I have these two lists. list_1 has data for 2002 only, whereas list_2 has data from 2001 to 2018. I want first to bind them and then for each country and respective year to keep the max value of the two.

```
1 2002   Australia     2404
2 2002 New Zealand       90
3 2002        Fiji       37


    time            exporter quantity
1   2001               China        0
2   2001                Fiji        0
3   2001        South Africa        0
4   2001              Brazil        0
5   2001              Greece        0
6   2001              Turkey        0
7   2001         New Zealand        1
8   2001  Korea, Republic of        0
40  2002           Australia        0
......
29  2002                Fiji      113
34  2002         New Zealand       18
.......


I used bind_rows to combine the two lists:

df <- bind_rows(list_1, list_2)

It then becomes:

    time            exporter quantity
1   2002           Australia     2404
2   2002         New Zealand       90
3   2002                Fiji       37
4   2001               China        0
5   2001                Fiji        0
6   2001        South Africa        0
7   2001              Brazil        0
8   2001              Greece        0
9   2001              Turkey        0
10  2001         New Zealand        1
11  2001  Korea, Republic of        0
12  2001           Singapore        0
13  2001            Malaysia        0
14  2001             Bahrain        0
...........
```

In the new bindlist, I expect that countries: Australia, Fiji and New Zealand would have 2404, 90 and 113 as values for the year 2002. The rest of the countries will remain the same because they do not appear in list_1. So, the code I am looking for will compare countries for same years e.g. Australia for 2002.....2018 of list_1 and 2002...2018 of list_2 and retain the max quantity of that year and country in the new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following `dplyr` script on your `df` to get the output you want.

```r
library(dplyr)
df%>% group_by(time, exporter) %>%
  filter(quantity == max(quantity)) %>%
  arrange(desc(time, exporter, quantity))
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# # A tibble: 11 x 3
# # Groups:   time, exporter [11]
#   time exporter    quantity
#   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
# 1  2002 Australia       2404
# 2  2002 New Zealand       90
# 3  2002 Fiji             113
# 4  2001 china              0
# 5  2001 Fiji               0
# 6  2001 SA                 0
# 7  2001 Brazil             0
# 8  2001 Greece             0
# 9  2001 Turkey             0
# 10 2001 New Zealand        1
# 11 2001 KRP                0
```

## Data

```r
#dput(list_1)
structure(list(time = c(2002, 2002, 2002), exporter = c("Australia", 
"New Zealand", "Fiji"), quantity = c(2404, 90, 37)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

#dput(list_2)
structure(list(time = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2002, 2002, 2002), exporter = c("china", "Fiji", "SA", 
"Brazil", "Greece", "Turkey", "New Zealand", "KRP", "Australia", 
"Fiji", "New Zealand"), quantity = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 113, 18)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")

#dput(df)
structure(list(time = c(2002, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002), exporter = c("Australia", 
"New Zealand", "Fiji", "china", "Fiji", "SA", "Brazil", "Greece", 
"Turkey", "New Zealand", "KRP", "Australia", "Fiji", "New Zealand"
), quantity = c(2404, 90, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 113, 
18)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```